# What are my options for hosting a web form in a banner?

Tags: forms, banner-ads

I have a client that will be running a 728x90 banner that expands to 728x315 upon rollover. They want to include a form in the expanded state that submits info to our server and displays a confirmation page WITHOUT navigating to a separate site. My initial thoughts were to use an iframe or JSONP, but:

- With an iframe, I see no reliable way to communicate back to the hosting page that the form was submitted successfully and the banner can shrink to its normal size. Since javascript cannot communicate across domain boundaries in this fashion, I think I'm out of luck if this is a requirement.
- JSONP supports get requests only. Also, it is unclear whether the banner ad publisher allows the inclusion of custom stylesheets / javascript (most likely not).
- Custom flash banner that accesses a web service (YUCK...)

Are there any other options?

I already told the client that this was a non-standard requirement that simply may not be doable, depending on the ad publisher platform and target sites, but now I'm stuck coming up with creative ways to make it happen.

Comment: I would say flash is the simplest, modern browsers support [postmessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284251/close-iframe-and-refresh-parent-cross-domain?lq=1) for easy cross domain iframe access but you would need to include js into the host page

Comment: @mika; web forms should (IMHO) never be implemented in flash. So much of the expected browser UI functionality is either broken or must be replicated that it becomes either an excessively poor experience or an unnecessary time consuming endeavor. Ever seen a drop down you couldn't scroll with the mouse, for example? At the far extreme end of suckage, I've even seen flash forms that didn't support tab field order properly.

Comment: @Chris Ever heard of RIAs? looking forward to see your final product... Please keep us posted!